# How much T4 thyroid is equivalent to an amount of T3?

Tags: medications, drug-metabolism

How much T4 thyroid is equivalent to an amount of T3? E.g. will x T4 generally be created to 1/2x T3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://healthunlocked.com/thyroiduk/posts/789489/t3-vs-t4-read-t3-five-times-strength-t4.-also-t3-ten-times-stronger.-which-is-it-penny) is the best answer I could find (from a page with more discussion):

> In a mythical "normal" human, around one third of the T4 is converted
>   to T3. So you could argue that T3 is "three times as strong as T4".
>
> When taking tablets, for example, changing from T4 only to mixed T3
>   and T4, it is common to estimate on the basis of T4 being one quarter
>   the "strength" of T3.
>
> So, 100 mcg T4 (thyroxine) could be similar to 25 mcg of T3
>   (liothyronine) OR 50 mcg of T4 plus 12.5 mcg of T3.
>
> This seems a reasonable basis for estimating doses but it is no better
>   than an informed guess.
>
> BUT if you are NOT converting properly this falls down. Imagine if you
>   are taking 100 mcg of thyroxine and NONE of it is converting. So you
>   have NO T3. You then take just 10 mcg of T3 and that has an effect
>   which the T4 NEVER had. So there really is no way you can think of one
>   being stronger than the other. One does something; the other does not

Comment: Welcome to Health! Please try to avoid answering with only quotes. Referencing to a reliable source is a great way to add to the credibility of an answer, but you must also explain how that citation answers the question. Quote-only answers don't add any value to the internet and are a bad practice, especially during a site's beta period. Instead, try to use your own words and experience and relate those to the source.